# Google Tag Manager tags build up with page loads in Single Page Website

Tags: single-page-application, google-tag-manager

I have a single page application linked to Google Tag Manager. I have a custom page load event setup so the tag fires when a "new page loads" (SPA page load).

However seeing that it is a SPA app the DOM doesn't reload completely on page load. My issue with this is that tags that fire on "page load" build up because the page isn't actually refreshed completely.

I was wondering if somebody had a good workflow for getting around this within Google Tag Manager?

An example is below.

URL:

mywebsite.com

Tags:

```
<script> console.log("my script"); </script>
```

URL 2:

mywebsite.com/about

Tags

```
<script> console.log("my script"); </script>
<script> console.log("my script"); </script>
```

URL 3:

mywebsite.com/work

Tags

```
<script> console.log("my script"); </script>
<script> console.log("my script"); </script>
<script> console.log("my script"); </script>
```

And so on depending on how many pages they visit.

Comment: Use custom events instead of pageviews. Set different pages to have different custom events, but these custom events also trigger a pageview.